# Regex to find macro value from a html string

Tags: c#, regex, macros

In my case **using c#** , string within square brackets from a html(as string) have to find, which may have white spaces after string (ie) **[userprinicipalname ]**.Also it may have white space before before sting (ie) **[  userprinicipalname]** ,since it is from html "&nbsp" is added for white space (I have used trim(),but it can not able to trim &nbsp before the string) ..Hence please help me to know the **Regex to get the trimmed(without white spaces or &nbsp before and after)value exactly within the square bracket alone ?**

[debugged state of macro replacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU8pk.png)

Comment: Why not do one more replace: `attribute.Replace("&nbsp;", string.empty);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html)` first,then use `Trim`

Comment: I can`t use HttpUtility in my c# class as it doesn`t show for any reference to add !!,pls help me how to overcome this ?

Comment: If you are using .NET Framework 4 *Client Profile*, switch to .NET Framework 4, or .NET Framework 4.5, etc. Then add a reference to System.Web.dll.

Comment: Thank u #Sky Fang, my problem is solved by  ur answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Replace(source, @"^\s+", "");` or `sourceString.Replace(" ",string.empty)`.

Comment: I have white space before string as ["&nbsp;"userprincipalname],please see the image link in my question above "debugged state of macro replacement"

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[[; ])(\w+)
```

try to use this regex match the attribute,

https://regex101.com/r/nF0rZ5/4

Comment: This regex skips the macros with white space or "&nbsp" rather than retrieve the trimmed value.                                                                              Note:      I have =>"[  userprincipalname]" (or) "["&nbsp;" displayname]"                         ..         I want => "userprincipalname" (or) "displayname"